# How to mark unsaved lines in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: text, sublimetext3, text-editor

I want to know which lines I changed in the file since the last save. How can I configure Sublime Text 3 so it will mark it near the line number?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Marking%20Changed%20Rows

Answer (score -1):

try 
Preferences -> Setting user

```
"highlight_modified_tabs": true
```